# Wiring low voltage around a corner

Tags: data-wiring, low-voltage

I tried grokking some of the other questions here, since I'm sure this is a duplicate -- but for the life of me I can't figure any of them out.

I'm looking to hide coaxial/ethernet wiring that either enters through the closet of my living room, or right next to the closet entrance. I'm actually trying to run the wiring horizontally to cover it up with a nice wall plate that would be installed next to the power outlet on the wall.

Unfortunately, for both wires, I'm not sure where they originate from, and there is no attic above, just a bedroom (which I hesitate to drill holes into the hardwood floor we paid to refinish).

I've kind of gathered three options of how to achieve what I'd like:

1. Remove the floor molding and run the wires horizontally that way.
2. Remove sections of drywall (which I don't really know how to patch).
3. Figure out how to get the coaxial from the closet to the wall in a 45 degree angle and put the plate close to where the ethernet wire comes out of the wall.

What would be some of your opinions here? I hope the diagram below sheds some light into what I'm dealing with and looking to achieve.

[image]

**Edit:** This is an actual picture

[image]

Comment: With low voltage(coax/phone/door bell) wiring, your imagination is the limit.  Household(lights/outlets) wiring you must go by codes.  Number 1 behind the moulding will probably be the easiest for you, if you are careful where you put the nails in.

Comment: @crip659...how easy is it to put said molding back in?

Comment: A picture would help here, there are many ways this can be done, just need to visually see to forward an answer.

Comment: @Johnliverpool, I can definitely send a real picture too later tonight!

Comment: Moulding is just decoration.  It is usually just held on by finishing(small) nails, so pulling it off is easy and putting it back on, just needs to nail it on.  Nails in wires bad.  I imagine if you ran out of nails, bubble gum would work just as well(I have not used bubble gum for more than fifty years).

Answer (score 2):

In the US the trim at the bottom of the wall where it meets the floor is Baseboard.  This may be your "floor molding"

Carefully remove a section of that molding and take a look at what's behind it.
Often there is a gap between the floor and the drywall Vertically or between the floor and the wall itself, horizontally.  The horizontal gap between the floor and the wall should remain undisturbed so the flooring can expand and contract.  Only about 1/4 inch (7mm) is needed.

The best bet is using the vertical gap, and if needed some  horizontal space between the wall and floor if it exceeds the 1/4 inch.  You can usually get the cable and wire in there.

They are low voltage so covering them is not an issue.

You then should be able to fish a wire down from the wall plate opening to the cable and wire, to pull them up.  You may need a small hole in the drywall, but it can be covered by the molding.

As said by Crip659, be careful where you nail the molding back to the wall.

You are set to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't want to do any drywall repair.

Replace your quarter round at the baseboard, from the closet to the location of the wall plate with a 1/4 round base cable cover:

[image]

Then use a regular rectangular/square/half round cable cover up to the required location on the wall.  You may want some kind of surface mount box to terminate the cables.
[image]
[image]